# erro $_post não sei onde estou errando!

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

`$cpfcnpj_tomador   = $_POST['txtCpfCnpjTomador'];
$numero_rps        = $_POST['txtRpsNumero'];
$data_rps          = $_POST['txtDataRps'];
$valor_rps         = $_POST['txtValorRps'];
$cpfcnpj_prestador = $_POST['txtCpfCnpjPrestador'];
$email_tomador     = $_POST['txtEmailtomador'];
$especificacao     = $_POST['cmbEspecificacao'];
$descricao         = $_POST['txtDescricao'];`

ERRO:

```
( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: txtCpfCnpjTomador in C:\wamp64\www\enota\site\inc\ouvidoria\cadastro.php on line 22 Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location 1  0.0010  251048  {main}( )   ...\cadastro.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: txtRpsNumero in C:\wamp64\www\enota\site\inc\ouvidoria\cadastro.php on line 23 Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location 1  0.0010  251048  {main}( )   ...\cadastro.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: txtDataRps in C:\wamp64\www\enota\site\inc\ouvidoria\cadastro.php on line 24 Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location 1  0.0010  251048  {main}( )   ...\cadastro.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: txtValorRps in C:\wamp64\www\enota\site\inc\ouvidoria\cadastro.php on line 25 Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location 1  0.0010  251048  {main}( )   ...\cadastro.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: txtCpfCnpjPrestador in C:\wamp64\www\enota\site\inc\ouvidoria\cadastro.php on line 26 Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location 1  0.0010  251048  {main}( )   ...\cadastro.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: txtEmailtomador in C:\wamp64\www\enota\site\inc\ouvidoria\cadastro.php on line 27 Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location 1  0.0010  251048  {main}( )   ...\cadastro.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: cmbEspecificacao in C:\wamp64\www\enota\site\inc\ouvidoria\cadastro.php on line 28 Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location 1  0.0010  251048  {main}( )   ...\cadastro.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: txtDescricao in C:\wamp64\www\enota\site\inc\ouvidoria\cadastro.php on line 29 Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location 1  0.0010  251048  {main}( )   ...\cadastro.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: btCadastrar in C:\wamp64\www\enota\site\inc\ouvidoria\cadastro.php on line 32 Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location 1  0.0010  251048  {main}( )   ...\cadastro.php:0
```

Comment: O erro sugere que você não postou nada com os names correspondentes. pode mostrar o form ?

Answer (score 0):

As variáveis `$_POST` não estão definidas, verifique no seu formulário se o `action` e `method` estão informados. Exemplo:

`<form method="post" action="cadastro.php"> ... </form>`

Answer (score -3):

Nesse caso seu formulário deve estar mais ou menos assim:

```css
label{min-width: 135px;display: inline-table;}
```

```html
<form action="cadastro.php" method="POST">
    <label for="txtCpfCnpjTomador">txtCpfCnpjTomador</label>
    <input type="text" name="txtCpfCnpjTomador" id="txtCpfCnpjTomador">
    <br><br>
    <label for="txtRpsNumero">txtRpsNumero</label>
    <input type="text" name="txtRpsNumero" id="txtRpsNumero">
    <br><br>
    <label for="txtDataRps">txtDataRps</label>
    <input type="text" name="txtDataRps" id="txtDataRps">
    <br><br>
    <label for="txtValorRps">txtValorRps</label>
    <input type="text" name="txtValorRps" id="txtValorRps">
    <br><br>
    <label for="txtCpfCnpjPrestador">txtCpfCnpjPrestador</label>
    <input type="text" name="txtCpfCnpjPrestador" id="txtCpfCnpjPrestador">
    <br><br>
    <label for="txtEmailtomador">txtEmailtomador</label>
    <input type="text" name="txtEmailtomador" id="txtEmailtomador">
    <br><br>
    <label for="cmbEspecificacao">cmbEspecificacao</label>
    <input type="text" name="cmbEspecificacao" id="cmbEspecificacao">
    <br><br>
    <label for="txtDescricao">txtDescricao</label>
    <input type="text" name="txtDescricao" id="txtDescricao">
    <br><br>
    <button>Enviar</button>
</form>
```